# Precision Score - TypeError: 'list' object is not callable

Tags: python-3.x, scikit-learn, precision-recall

I'm getting the following error when using `precision_score` from `scikit-learn`.

```
precision_score(y_sm[test_index], prediction)
>>> TypeError: 'list' object is not callable

prediction.shape 
>>> (2830,)

y_sm[test_index].shape
>>> (2830,)
```

What is wrong here? Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: How about you try `precision_score(np.array(y_sm[test_index],np.array(prediction))` after importing `numpy as np` of course

Comment: Oh, I got it. I had initiated a `list` with a name `precision_score` and that was tripping me up. Sorry, for the inconvenience everyone.

Comment: That's what I though. So question accepted and answered. cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure that you do not have defined a `list` with name `precision_score` ?

Try:

```
print(precision_score)
```

Does it return a list or a function?

Answer (score 1):

You can check your type with:
`type(prediction)`
probably it will return: list.

Based on the documentation of [precision_score](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.precision_score.html):

```
parameters: 

y_true : 1d array-like, or label indicator array / sparse matrix

    Ground truth (correct) target values.
y_pred : 1d array-like, or label indicator array / sparse matrix

    Estimated targets as returned by a classifier.
```

You have to use an 1d array-like:

```
import numpy as np

prediction_a = np.asarray(prediction, dtype=np.float32)
y_sm[test_index]_a = np.asarray(y_sm[test_index], dtype=np.float32)

precision_score(y_sm[test_index]_a, prediction_a)
```

Comment: Hey, I had initiated a list with a name precision_score and that was tripping me up. Sorry, for the inconvenience everyone. Do you know, how can I close this question?